# Declared target fragment that does not belong to this FragmentManager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, fragmentmanager, fragmenttransaction

I've got a simple setup:
[image: explaination]

Code:

ActivityHaupt -> FragmentHaupt:

```
final FragmentHaupt fragment = new FragmentHaupt();
final FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction(); 
transaction.add(R.id.frameLHaupt, fragment, null);
transaction.disallowAddToBackStack(); 
transaction.commit();
```

FragmentHaupt -> FragmentViewP:

```
FragmentViewPfragment2 = new FragmentViewP();
fragment2.setTargetFragment(FragmentHaupt.this, 12); //AppConstant.FRAGMENT_CODE = 12

FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLHaupt, fragment2);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

FragmentViewP-> FragmentAddDriver:

```
FragmentAddDriver ldf = new FragmentAddDriver ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putString("firstname", vName.getText().toString());
args.putString("lastname", nName.getText().toString());
args.putString("drivername", dName.getText().toString());
ldf.setArguments(args);

ldf.setTargetFragment(FragmentHaupt.newInstance("firstP","lastP"), 12); 
FragmentManager fragmentManager =  getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frameLHaupt, ldf);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

When I try opening the FragmentAddDriver activity, I receive the error in the title. What can the problem be? I am using always the same FragmentManager (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager)?

What am I missing?

Comment: Why are you passing a brand new instance of `FragmentHaupt` to `setTargetFragment`? That new fragment isn't add to any FraemtManager.

Comment: @ianhanniballake for some reason fragment manager doesn't allow me using h fragmenthaupt.class

Answer (score 0):

With the code here:

```
ldf.setTargetFragment(FragmentHaupt.newInstance("firstP","lastP"), 12);
```

You're not actually going back to the FragmentHaupt. You're adding a new instance of it.

To actually go back you've to set tag when you add it in `MainActivity`

```
transaction.add(R.id.frameLHaupt, fragment, "FragmentHaupt");
```

And inside `FragmentViewP` you've to find it using that tag.

```
ldf.setTargetFragment(fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("FragmentHaupt"), 12);
```

This way you'll be able to go back to that instance.

Comment: I'll try it when i get code and let u know if it works, so i can mark ur answer as corrected :)

Comment: No, it doesnt work unfourtantly. altough I dont get an error when opening FragmentAddDriver, I always return to the FragmentViewP Fragment when using the following code: `        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), FragmentHaupt.class);
        intent.putExtra("pusyyname", 345);
        intent.putExtra("pussyadress", "jiii");
        getTargetFragment().onActivityResult(121, 12, intent);
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();`